# Matplotlib won't show minor ticks when using subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, subplot

I have several subplots and want to adjust the axis ticks settings by ax.tick_params. Everything works fine, however, the **minor** ticks are not shown. Here is a code example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0,1,100)
y = x*x

f, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1)

ax1.tick_params(axis="both", direction="in", which="both", right=False, top=True)
ax2.tick_params(axis="both", direction="in", which="both", right=True, top=False)

ax1.plot(x,y)
ax2.plot(x,-y)

plt.show()
```

I assumed that which=both would give me the minor ticks. However I need to add an additional

```
plt.minorticks_on()
```

which makes them visible **but only** in ax2.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With pyplot the danger is that you loose track of which one the current axes is that a command like `plt.minorticks_on()` operates on. Hence it would be beneficial to use the respective methods of the axes you're working with:

```
ax1.minorticks_on()
ax2.minorticks_on()
```

Answer (score 3):

`plt` would work on the current axis which is `ax2`  in your case. One way is to first enable them using the way you did and then specify the number of minor ticks using `AutoMinorLocator`

```
from matplotlib.ticker import AutoMinorLocator

ax1.tick_params(axis="both", direction="in", which="both", right=False, top=True)
ax2.tick_params(axis="both", direction="in", which="both", right=True, top=False)

ax1.plot(x,y)
ax2.plot(x,-y)

for ax in [ax1, ax2]:
    ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator(4))
    ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator(4))
```

[image]